# Django Rest Framework User Foreign Key

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using the base Django Auth User for my user handling and have authentication working. Now I am trying to create a Post method for my Rest API that automatically gets the user from the request, then gets all of the data input, and saves it.

I have tried various attempts at serialization. I also had this working as just a plain Django website, but now things are getting interesting making it into an API.

Here is my model:

```
class UserIncome(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
                       on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    preTaxIncome = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    savingsRate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    taxRate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

Here is my Serializer(Base, no attempts at making the foreign key):

```
class UserIncomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.UserIncome
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'preTaxIncome', 'savingsRate', 'taxRate')
```

Here is the view(Again, just the base. No attempts at foreign key):

```
class UserIncomeList(APIView):
    #List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        userIncome = models.UserIncome.objects.get(user=request.user)
        serializer = Serializers.UserIncomeSerializer(userIncome, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = Serializers.UserIncomeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Should I just make the foreign key the user ID and get that somehow?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out!

I removed the user field from the serializer, then in the post method of UserIncomeList I made the save method:

```
serializer.save(user = request.user)
```